# Filter issues that do not have any comment made by me (or any user) in JIRA, using JQL

Tags: jira

Is it possible to filter out issues in JIRA using JQL, that do not have any comments made by me but may or may not contain comments made by other users?

Comment: Pls add more detailed description for the Question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about ALM tools and not SQA or testing, maybe better asked on pm.SE instead. I think it is possible, read: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/247822/jira-advanced-query-for-searching-text-in-a-comment-field-in-a-ticket-does-not-appear-to-work

Answer (score 1):

Presumably one cannot comment on a ticket without having access rights to the project, so the question boils down to, "Is it possible to filter out issues in JIRA that do not have any comments?".

No, it is not possible without installing additional Jira plugs.  See for example [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11814781/100464), which recommends using the Jira Toolkit Plugin to create a custom field that counts the ticket's comments.

Comment: Edited the question to be more clear.